# Internet explorer ignores flash mms.cfg settings

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, flash, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I have the following mms.cfg in

- `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System\mms.cfg`
- `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System\mms.cfg`
- `%windir%System32\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg`
- `%windir%\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg`

```
EOLUninstallDisable=1
SilentAutoUpdateEnable=0
EnableAllowList=1
AutoUpdateDisable=0
AllowListUrlPattern=http://localhost/flash/
ErrorReportingEnable=1
EnableInsecureLocalWithFileSystem=1
```

With this after I set my PC date to something in 2021. I'm able to run Flash in

- Chrome - Which uses the config in `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System\mms.cfg`
- Edge Chromium - Which uses the config in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System\mms.cfg`
- Firefox - `%windir%System32\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg`

Based on my understanding IE11 should be using the one from `%windir%System32\Macromed\Flash\mms.cfg` but for whatever reason it seems like it's ignoring it and the settings in this file have no effect and flash is still disabled.
[image]

Just to be on the 100% sure that IE uses that config file I've ran ProcMon and it seems like IE is actually opening the file as you can see in the picture.
[image]

My question is why is internet explorer ignoring this? And what can I do about it?
Other useful info:

- Firefox and Chromium browsers use 32.0.0.433
- IE11 uses 32.0.0.387 which is the windows embedded version of flash.
- Tested on

  - Windows 10 Pro 10.0.18362
  - Windows 10 Pro 10.0.19041
  - Windows 10 Home 10.0.18362
- I took Flash player version 32.0.0.330 from an older version of Windows and I didn't even get the EOL behavior. This leads me to believe that this is a FP version issue and that version 32.0.0.387 which is distributed by MS might not support `AllowListUrlPattern`.

Things I've tried and didn't work include:

- Restarting the machine
- Setting the encoding of the .cfg to UTF-8.

Comment: I tried to test the issue on my side and found that when I try to modify the system date then site which contains flash content not able to match the certificates and it is not loading the contents. Browser also shows the warning that date and time are not correct. After some try system date and time get reset to the current date and time by itself within few seconds of modification. I want to conform with you how did you check and verify that above settings has applied or not. I noticed that Flash player settings manager looks little bit different then I seen it in other examples.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I have encountered the behaviors you're describing. The certificates problem occurs only on https, I'm running a local server and using `http://localhost/flash`. And the date reverting is something I'm experiencing on Windows Sandbox I have another questions on SU [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1583850/date-reverts-to-current-one-in-windows-sandbox), this does not happen on my actual machine.

Comment: On my machine IE is using Flash version 32.0.0.330 Can you please inform us how did you check whether the settings from file has been applied or not? Does the same setting works for the current date?

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT With `AllowListUrlPattern=http://localhost/flash/` flash continues to work  after setting the date to something in 2021, IE is the only one which still exhibits the EOL behavior which is not working and showing the flash logo with an info icon

Comment: I unchecked the [Synchronized with an internet time server](https://imgur.com/a/uaHcsy3) option and it helped to modify the future date. After that I noticed that it shows the flash logo with info icon in other browsers but IE still works on my side. It works with any URL. You can notice that I am accessing the example from internet. [See here](https://imgur.com/a/e0iB74d)

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT  I've just reproduced it on second PC and I have exactly the same behavior I described in the question. I've attached an extra image with IE and Chrome side by side to show what I'm getting. As for you getting the exact opposite behavior I have no idea, maybe IE cached something on your side.

Comment: I restarted the machine couple of times, visit the page in the private mode and flash is working in the IE 11 browser. So I don't think there is any cache issue. Can you please inform us your Windows OS build? We can try to make a test with that specific build to check for the issue. Also let us know, if there are any other settings involved on your side.

Comment: I tried test the issue with the Win 10 Pro and I am able to reproduce the issue with it. As we know that the IE browser will retire in the 2021. I am not sure whether this config is not working due to this reason. At present, I did not get solution or a work around for this issue. I suggest you provide your feedback to Microsoft via Feedback hub app on your Win 10 OS. Also try to ask the question on [Adobe forum](https://community.adobe.com/) to get their opinion on this issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT can you share your OS info? Also MS release [this](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/09/04/update-adobe-flash-end-support) recently so I doubt this is the desired behaviour.

Comment: I had reproduce this issue with the Win 10 Pro 1909 OS build 18363.1082. Another thing I noticed that it works fine on the Win 10 Enterprise version.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I can confirm that you don't experience the EoL behavior on that version of Windows because you do not have [KB4561600](https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4561600) applied yet. Once you do you're going to upgrade FP 32.0.0.387 and get the same behavior on Win enterprise as well.

Comment: I try to search for the issue to see whether there is an official document available that can give the information about this change but I did not found any relevant document. If we try to use those settings in the current date then it works fine. I suggest trying to use current date settings. In the future, if I get any relevant information then I will inform you about it. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck with this? I'm getting same results in IE on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19041 and FP 32.0.0.387. Moving the clock forward displays EOL icon link, ignoring mms.cfg config.

Answer (score 7):

I tested this on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.19041 and Flash Player 32.0.0.387 with same results.

I then ran Windows updates which installed Flash Player 32.0.0.445.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4580325/security-update

This version respected `mms.cfg` settings as expected.

My `mms.cfg` was placed in `%windir%\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash` and `%windir%\System32\Macromed\Flash`

and it looks like this:

```
EOLUninstallDisable=1
EnableAllowList=1
AllowListUrlPattern=*://*.mydomain.com/
AllowListUrlPattern=*://localhost/
AllowListUrlPattern=*://localhost:5311/
```

Also, having played around with different dates I've determined the cut off date to be 01/12/2021.

Comment: For "Flash was not detected on your browser. To stream videos, Flash version 10.0 or higher is required.", make sure it is applied on `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Pepper Data\Shockwave Flash\System\mms.cfg` for Google Chrome to work

Comment: Is working with `*://` instead of `https://` and a final slash on the patterns???

Answer (score 3):

Take a loot at article here https://community.adobe.com/t5/flash-player/ie-11-ignores-allowlisturlpattern-in-mms-cfg/td-p/11426041?page=1

Basically, try change the properties names:

- `EnableAllowList` into `EnableWhiteList`
- `AllowlistPreview` into `WhitelistPreview`
- `AllowListUrlPattern` into `WhitelistUrlPattern`

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem in `IE 11` and found the answer at the this [page](https://community.adobe.com/t5/flash-player/ie-11-ignores-allowlisturlpattern-in-mms-cfg/td-p/11426041?page=1).

In short, using the `EnableWhitelist`, `WhitelistPreview`, `WhitelistUrlPattern` flags instead of `EnableAllowList`, `AllowListPreview`, `AllowListUrlPattern` in the `mms.cfg` file worked for me.

My `mms.cfg` file is in below path:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash
```

Thanks